# python scipy convolve2d seems incorrect

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, convolution

my aim is to create and visualize the partial derivatives of a image (2D). I´ll do this with the first finite central difference equation
[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) .

the partial derivative of F with respect to x is

df(x,y)/dx=f(x+1,y)-f(x-1,y)

we can write this as a convolve kernel H=[-1,0,1] and should get the same result
by convolve the image with the kernel

dfx=F*H

Here is my source-code:

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
from PIL import *
from scipy import signal as sg

#create artifical image with constant positive slope 
myImage=zeros((5,5),dtype=float)
for y in range(5):
    for x in range(5):
        myImage[y,x]=y+x
```

---

at first I create the *first central finite difference* for x and y by the convolve2d - function from the **scipy** modul (the short way)

```
kernel=array([[-1,0,1]])     #create first central finite difference kernel
pdx=sg.convolve2d(myImage,kernel,"same")   #dI(x,y)/dx
```

---

and now I create the same using loops

```
H,W=myImage.shape[0:2]
pdx=zeros((H,W),dtype=float)
for y in range(1,H-1):
    for x in range(1,W-1):
        pdx.itemset(y,x,im.item(y,x+1)-im.item(y,x-1))
```

Let´s see the results:

pdx - kernel method by convolve2d

```
array([[-1., -2., -2., -2.,  3.],
   [-2., -2., -2., -2.,  4.],
   [-3., -2., -2., -2.,  5.],
   [-4., -2., -2., -2.,  6.],
   [-5., -2., -2., -2.,  7.]])
```

pdx - finite difference by loops

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  0.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I´m confused about the results. Why has the kernel method a negative slope ? 
To get the same results i have to flip the kernel to H=[1,0,-1], but this is mathematically not correct.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: As a sidenote, you can create `myImage` much faster with broadcasting:  `x = np.arange(5.)` `myImage = x[:, None] + x`

Comment: An aside: Note that your convolution kernel H=[1, 0, -1] is a modified Prewitt operator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prewitt_operator) for which scipy.ndimage has a handy call.

Comment: Thanks for asking this. :D

Answer (score 9):

The reason for the difference is two-fold:

1. You've forgotten the flipping of the kernel in the mathematical definition of a convolution.
2. You're assuming different boundary conditions than `scipy.signal`

Also, for what you're doing, you almost definitely want `scipy.ndimage.convolve` instead of `scipy.signal.convolve2d`.  The defaults for `ndimage` are set up to work with images, and it's more efficient for limited-precision integer data, which is the norm for images.

---

To reproduce your loop version with `scipy.signal`, you'd need to reverse the kernel, as you've noticed.

This is the mathematical definition of a convolution.  The kernel is flipped before being "swept by". For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Convolution3.PNG

---

Second, `scipy.signal.convolve2d` pads the boundaries with zeros by default, while you're simply not operating on the boundaries.  To reproduce your boundary conditions with `scipy.signal.convolve2d`, use `boundary='symm'` (For this specific kernel, anyway... In general, you're just ignoring the boundaries, which `convolve2d` doesn't have an option for.)

---

Finally, for your purposes (image processing), it's far more efficient to use `scipy.ndimage.convolve`.  In this case (a 1D kernel), it's most efficient to use `scipy.ndimage.convolve1d`.  E.g. `scipy.ndimage.convolve1d(data, [1, 0, -1], axis=0)`

Answer (score 3):

Convolution of *f* and *g* is the integral of *f(x') g(x - x')* over *dx'*.  The effect of this is that the kernel is *flipped*.  Either use the flipped kernel, or use `scipy.ndimage.correlate` which does *f(x') g(x + x')*, so the kernel is kept in the same direction as input.

See [Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) for more information, and for some info on finite differences, see [Python finite difference functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18993405/1730674).

Comment: +1 Beat me to it!  I'll leave mine up, just because I was in the middle of writing it :)