# Error calculating curvature with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate the curvature of a 2D curve at each point using the [formula here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Local_expressions). The problem I am having is that while I am getting a constant value as it should be, this value is not the correct one. Here is my code:

```
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter1d
import numpy as np

def curvature(x, y):
    #first and second derivative
    x1 = gaussian_filter1d(x, sigma=1, order=1, mode='wrap')
    x2 = gaussian_filter1d(x, sigma=1, order=2, mode='wrap')
    y1 = gaussian_filter1d(y, sigma=1, order=1, mode='wrap')
    y2 = gaussian_filter1d(y, sigma=1, order=2, mode='wrap')
    return np.abs(x1*y2 - y1*x2) / np.power(x1**2 + y1**2, 3/2)

# make circle data
alpha = np.linspace(-np.pi/2,np.pi/2, 1000)
R = 5
x = R*np.cos(alpha)
y = R*np.sin(alpha)

>>> 1 / curvature(x, y)
array([  9.60e+02,   5.65e+01,   4.56e-01,   1.41e-02,   6.04e-01,
         6.04e-01,   6.04e-01,   6.04e-01,   6.04e-01,   6.04e-01,
         6.04e-01,   6.04e-01,   6.04e-01,   6.04e-01,   6.04e-01,
         ...
```

I was expecting to get something close to a 5. Can somebody help me spot the error or suggest a more robust way to do this? In practice my x,y points are not evenly spaced.

EDIT: I am using `gaussian_filter1d` instead of `np.gradient` for the derivative because it was shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18993405/4480499) that this is a more robust method, especially for the second derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for curvature depends on the first and second derivatives of `x` and `y`.

Your code is assuming that the gaussian_filter1d is the same as the first derivative of `x`.  It is not.

Look up `np.gradient(x,dalpha)` where `dalpha` is the step size.

**edit** If you want to go through `gaussian_filter1d`, you should be alright but the calculation of the second derivative is not doing what you expect.  Here is some working code where I've done 2 first derivatives to get `x2` and `y2`:

```
import numpy as np
def curvature(x, y):
    #first and second derivative
    dalpha = np.pi/1000
    x1 = gaussian_filter1d(x, sigma=1, order=1, mode='wrap')
    x2 = gaussian_filter1d(x1, sigma=1, order=1, mode='wrap')
    y1 = gaussian_filter1d(y, sigma=1, order=1, mode='wrap')
    y2 = gaussian_filter1d(y1, sigma=1, order=1, mode='wrap')
    return np.abs(x1*y2 - y1*x2) / np.power(x1**2 + y1**2, 3./2)

# make circle data
alpha = np.linspace(-np.pi/2,np.pi/2, 1000)
R = 5
x = R*np.cos(alpha)
y = R*np.sin(alpha)

print 1/curvature(x,y)
```

After a lot of careful checking I saw that `y2` wasn't looking much like `-y` and similarly for `x2`.  The change I made from your code is that now `y2` and `x2` come from `y1` and `x1` with `gaussian_filter1d` having `order=1`.  I don't know enough about what the filter is doing to be able to say why two passes through the filter with `order=1` seems to work but a single pass with `order=2` doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure? I took this technique from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991408/python-finite-difference-functions) where the `gaussian_filter1d`resulted the best method to estimate the derivative.

Comment: So you are saying that the answer I linked is wrong or did I apply it wrongly?

Comment: @Joel, I went with `gaussian_filter1d` instead of `np.gradient` because the linked answer proved that this is a more robust method, especially for the second derivative. I also observed the same in my tests.

Comment: @Joel, I didn't include the `dalpha` because they cancel out in the formula, you can test it yourself, it doesn't change the result.