# Higher order finite differences in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have sampled functions on 2D and 3D numpy arrays and I need a way to take partial derivatives from these arrays. I could code the finite difference schemes manually, but I need more than just 2nd order accuracy, probably 4th or even sixth order. With higher accuracy orders coding it manually quickly becomes tedious, especially because I need it for arrays of different dimensions.

Is there function in numpy or scipy or some other package that can do that *conveniently*?

Comment: Are you looking for [`numpy.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)?

Comment: Have you seen this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991408/python-finite-difference-functions) it has a really good discussion and a solution — this might be what you’re looking for ?

Comment: Nah, probably not `numpy.diff`. After searching for information on finite differences, I'm not sure how accuracy orders work, but I'm pretty sure `numpy.diff` doesn't support them.

Comment: Not really, numpy.diff is for the n-th difference along a certain access, but it doesn't provide me with the finite difference weights appropriate for the desired accuracy and derivative order.

Comment: @Hamza: yes, have seen that, it's a good one, but with that solution I would have to dig out and insert the weights manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [findiff](https://github.com/maroba/findiff) package. It let's you conveniently take derivatives of numpy arrays of any dimension, any derivative order and any desired accuracy order. The project website says that it features:

- Differentiate arrays of any number of dimensions along any axis
- Partial derivatives of any desired order
- Standard operators from vector calculus like gradient, divergence and curl
- Can handle uniform and non-uniform grids
- Can handle arbitrary linear combinations of derivatives with constant and variable coefficients
- Accuracy order can be specified
- Fully vectorized for speed
- Calculate raw finite difference coefficients for any order and accuracy for uniform and non-uniform grids